# Does plotly JavaScript support multi selection dropdown?

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to add a multi-selection dropdown to my plotly chart; however, I can only find dash (python) supports such feature.

Does plotly JavaScript has built-in multi-selection dropdown at all (pure JavaScript not python)? If not, I can just create a generic multi-selection dropdown outside the plotly framework.

Or is there anyway to reverse engineer into JavaScript from the multi-selection dropdown generated by dash?

Comment: You could always pull in `dash-core-components` as a project dependency and then use the `Dropdown` component inside your customised version of it. https://github.com/plotly/dash-core-components/blob/dev/src/components/Dropdown.react.js

Comment: @miqh Do you have an example I can look at?

Comment: As in a complete implementation of a multi-selection dropdown that you're asking for? No, unfortunately. However, my cursory understanding of Dash is that it actually uses that JS implementation for dropdowns that I linked previously. You can always define a custom React component that imports `Dropdown` and customises it as necessary?

Comment: Or is there any example that imports any dash core js (not just dropdown)? I am having difficulties with js module and other stuff to make the import work...

Comment: Plotly provide a [boilerplate](https://github.com/plotly/dash-component-boilerplate) for creating your own components  and [this page](https://dash.plotly.com/plugins) gives an overview of how the JS to Python integration works.